# Schedule method in Python3 does not work for me

Tags: python-3.x, flask, timer, schedule

I have written a class that has a method that counts some changes and then makes comparison, and sends a email. 
However, sending email should occur only once a day, but for now it does that every minute. 
I implemented a schedule method but it does not seem to be working, as send email stops completly. 
I'm very new to Python and flask and I'm not sure what I'm actually doing.
Here is my class:

```
class AlertChecker(Thread):
def __init__(self, models, db):
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.db = db
    self.models = models
    self.minute = 60
    self.hour = self.minute * 60
    self.day = 24 * self.hour
    self.week = 7 * self.day
    #gather the changes of IPs
def get_changes(self, scans, limit):
    changes = []
    filtered_scans = [scan for scan in scans if scan.timestamp > limit]

    length = len(filtered_scans)
    if length < 2:
        return changes
    for i in range(length-1):

        if self.compare_two_scans(filtered_scans[i], filtered_scans[i+1]):
            old_timestamp = str(filtered_scans[i].timestamp)[0:-7]
            new_timestamp = str(filtered_scans[i+1].timestamp)[0:-7]

            change = {"old": filtered_scans[i].as_dict(), "new": filtered_scans[i+1].as_dict()}

            change['old']['timestamp'] = old_timestamp
            change['new']['timestamp'] = new_timestamp
            changes.append(change)
    if len(changes) > 0:

    return changes

def compare_two_scans(self, one, two):
    first = [item.ip for item in one.iplist]
    second = [item.ip for item in two.iplist]
    common = set(first).intersection(second)

    if len(common) == len(one.iplist) and len(common) == len(two.iplist):

        return False

    return True    
#Timer doe not work
def job():
    count_changes(self)

    return

    schedule.every(20).minutes.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(60) # wait one minute

def count_changes(self):
    stamp = datetime.now()
    upper_limit = stamp - timedelta(days=7)
    lower_limit = stamp - timedelta(days=2)

    nameservers = models.NameServer.query.all()
    nameservers = [item.name for item in nameservers]
    domains = models.Domain.query.all()
    domains = [item.name for item in domains]
    changes = []
    upper_limit_changes = []
    lower_limit_changes = []

    for ns in nameservers:

        for domain in domains:
            scans = models.Scan.query.filter_by(nameserver=ns, domain=domain).all()
            upper_limit_changes.extend(self.get_changes(scans, upper_limit))
            lower_limit_changes.extend(self.get_changes(scans, lower_limit))

    return upper_limit_changes, lower_limit_changes

def run(self):
    done = False
    upper, lower = self.count_changes()
    if len(upper) > 0 or len(lower) > 0 :
        r = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/sendmail', json={'upper':upper, 'lower':lower})
```

Comment: Really, a better approach to this is to save your pending emails to a persistent location, then use an OS scheduling tool (such as cron) to call yor email send code reqularly.

Comment: I'm not familar with cron, and I'm not sure how  to save pending emails to a persistent location?

Comment: if you're using this code as it is, there are a lot of indentation errors and that might be the cause of why it is not working as expected coz some code might not be getting executed. I haven't read the logic yet. Please confirm if indentation is not the issue here.

Comment: The indentation is not the issue, I can run the code

Comment: The main question is how to schedule one particular task within the thread? is it even possible?